# Room database test fails to assert

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-testing

I am trying to test a room database connection, which is failing. There is no compile error, but I am getting a runtime error after running the test. I must be doing something wrong.

Can anyone please explain why this database test is failing?

The test class:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ItemRoomDatabaseTest {

    private lateinit var itemDao: ItemDao
    private lateinit var db: ItemRoomDatabase

    @Before
    fun createDb() {
        val context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()

        db = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context, ItemRoomDatabase::class.java)
            .allowMainThreadQueries()
            .build()

        itemDao = db.itemDao()
    }

    @After
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun closeDb() {
        db.close()
    }

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @Test
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun insertAndGetItem() = runBlockingTest {
        val boira = Item(0, "Boira", 0.35, 36)
        val apple = Item(0, "Apple", 0.60, 50)
        val mango = Item(0, "Mango", 2.10, 43)

        itemDao.insert(boira)
        itemDao.insert(apple)
        itemDao.insert(mango)

        val receivedItem = itemDao.getAllItems().asLiveData()

        assertThat(receivedItem.value?.size, equalTo(3))
    }
}
```

The DAO:

```
@Dao
interface ItemDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM item_table ORDER BY name ASC")
    fun getAllItems(): Flow<List<Item>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM item_table WHERE id = :id")
    fun getItem(id: Int): Flow<Item>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insert(item: Item)
    ....
```

The runtime error I am getting:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This job has not completed yet
    at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.getCompletionExceptionOrNull(JobSupport.kt:1190)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runBlockingTest(TestBuilders.kt:53)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runBlockingTest$default(TestBuilders.kt:45)
    at com.example.roomcrud.data.ItemRoomDatabaseTest.insertAndGetItem(ItemRoomDatabaseTest.kt:48)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why do you call it Compose database? Looks like Room database, and question looks not related to compose at all

Comment: Thanks! Changed the title now to avoid confusion. It is a Room database indeed, and I am working with Compose here.

Comment: You may be working with compose, it doesn't meant it's related to the issue. I see no composables here, issue seems only related to Room database. If I'm not missing something, you should remove compose from title and from tag

Comment: Though there might be something needed to do differently in compose. Done now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add the dependency 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$version'

then add InstantTask() rule-

@get:Rule
val instantExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
and let us know the result.

Comment: Thanks! Added that, but now getting this error: `junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected: <3>
     Got: was null`